# Executing a query in VB.NET causes GUI bug

Tags: sql, vb.net, user-interface, ms-access, oledbconnection

Whenever my program needs too query the database, it'll result in GUI bugs like the form fonts changing randomly, the form itself resizing,  the data in the datagrid being mixed together, and it affect the overall program, not just the form that is calling the query function.

I use this connection

```vb
 "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

 Public DBDA As OleDbDataAdapter
 Public DBDT As DataTable
 DBDT = New DataTable
 DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCmd)
 RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
```

and here is my Execute Query function:

```vb
Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
    'RESET QUERY STATS
    RecordCount = 0
    Exception = ""
    Try
        'OPEN A CONNECTION
        DBCon.Open()

        'CREATE DB COMMAND
        DbCmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBCon)

        'LOAD PARAMETERS INTO COMMAND
        Params.ForEach(Sub(Par) DbCmd.Parameters.Add(Par))

        'CLEAR PARAMETERS LIST
        Params.Clear()

        'EXECUTE COMMAND & FILL DATA
        DBDT = New DataTable
        DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(DbCmd)
        RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
    End Try

    'CLOSE CONNECTION
    If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
End Sub
```

and an example of how I query from a form

```vb
Private QC As New QueryControl
Public Sub RefreshGrid()
    'RUN QUERY
    QC.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Database")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(QC.Exception) Then MsgBox(QC.Exception) : Exit Sub
    'POPULATE DATAGRID
    Datagridview1.DataSource = QC.DBDT
 End Sub
```

I tried running the debugging the program while commenting each line individually and concluded that the ExecQuery() function is what causes the issue. Anyone met something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem of the form resizing. It was the 32 bit Ace provider. I downloaded the 64 bit Ace provider and installed it. In the solution properties uncheck the prefer 32 bit box and all should be well.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I downloaded the 64 bit versions and changed the target output from "All CPU" to "x64" and also had to modifiy the connection methods, in the server explorer on advanced properties I changed the Oledb services from Default to Enable All and ater all that It worked.
I also enabled the DPI awareness as stated in the previous post, but doing just that was not enough, I guess.

Comment: This drove me nuts for the longest time. I think it is in MS forums under "The Incredible Shrinking Form" :-)